# undefined method `popups_path' for #

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create model, view and controller but when I added form code on new.html.haml file. it started showing error. Routes are defined as follows

**model  popups.rb**

```
class Popups < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :slug, :pipelinetype
end
```

**controller popups_controller.rb**

```
class PopupsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @popups = Popups.new
  end

  def create
    @popups = Popups.new(params[:url])
    if @popups.save
      flash[:popups] = @popups.id
      redirect_to new_popups_url
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @popups = Popups.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @popups.url
  end

end
```

**Views popups - new.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @popups do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :body
  = f.input :pipelinetype
  = f.input :slug
  = f.submit
```

**routes.rb**   `resources :popups, :only => [:show, :new, :create]`

**migrate file**

```
create_table :popups do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.string :slug
      t.string :pipelinetype

      t.timestamps
    end
```

I am getting following errors on given urls

```
:3000/popups/new  -  undefined method `popups_index_path' for #

**:3000/popups   -**  
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for MainController
```

Initially I created model and controller with **popup** name but change it later to popups as suggested

Is there something wrong with code or routes or I am missing someting.

I used http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/ as reference

Comment: show 'new' action from controller, please

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: this code seems ok, make sure that you have no popups_path used in views/controllers (maybe in buttons or forms)

Comment: Make your routes plural. `resources :popups`

Comment: popup_index POST   /popup(.:format)      create
new_popup GET    /popup/new(.:format)  new
popup GET    /popup/:id(.:format)  show

Comment: That's really hard to read, Vikram. But @JustinLicata is correct, route should be plural.

Comment: @Jesper rake routes output pasted above

Comment: I made changes as you suggested but still getting errors. I updated my question with all details, can somebody help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Always remember when you use `resources`, you should be giving a ***plural name(i.e, popups in your case)***. If you want a ***singular name(i.e, popup)*** then use `resource` instead of `resources`.

For more Info, see [**Singular Resources**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Answer (score 0):

You have to  plurialize your routes.
`resources :popup, :only => [:show, :new, :create]`
Should be 
`resources :popups, only: [:show, :new, :create]`

Actually your routes look like that:

`popup_index POST  /popup(.:format)       popup#create`

`new_popup GET     /popup/new(.:format)   popup#new`

`popup GET         /popup/:id(.:format)   popup#show`

Comment: then I should change my controller name to popups_controller as well ?

Comment: because when i change it to plural it giving error - The action 'show' could not be found for MainController

Comment: Yes the controller name, and the folder with the views

Comment: its giving me the error - uninitialized constant PopupsController::Popup

Comment: and url would be /popup/new or /popups/new ?

Comment: /popups/new for popups#new

Comment: I made changes as you suggested but still getting errors. I updated my question with all details can you please look into it if you get time

Comment: Is it a public repo on github ? So I can take a look to the entire code ?